# Retrieve keyvault secured function keys from app configuration in angular code to call api

Tags: angular, typescript, azure-functions, azure-keyvault, api-key

I need to get the keyvault secrets value as function key to call azure functions api. The keyvault reference has been added to app configuration. I can access keyvault reference stored in app configuration but not the secrets. How to retrieve the API key / function key stored in keyvault to the angular code

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible. Also, is not recommended even if it were possible. if you could connect to key vault to retrieve secrets in JavaScript on client side, it's a huge security risk, as anyone could be able to access your secrets. it does not provide any security.

As a best practice you should never access secured resources directly from client code.

**But here is an example code provided by official site of npmjs, please refer this [blog post](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@azure/keyvault-secrets).**

Comment: May I know the best way to store the API key and retrieve the API key to call from angular code?